# Manipulating Jenkins Plugin Settings from Command-Line

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins

I have a Jenkins machine that gets deployed via a provided VM. I need to add a plugin and then set the settings via a script.

To install the plugin (thinBackup, fwiw), I wget the plugin as a .hpi, drop it to the plugins directory, and restart the Jenkins service (the plugin has no dependencies, so I don't need to worry further about that).

Now I need to set the plugin settings' values. I can't find any documentation as to where these settings would be found. Where would that settings file be located, and is there a better way other than brute forcing values into the file (such as an API)?

Answer (score 0):

Typical for my level of Google-fu -- search for a few hours and find nothing. Post a question to Stack Overflow. Find the answer on my own 20 minutes later :)

The answer is that the plugins appear to be storing their settings in the Jenkins home directory (as opposed to somewhere in the plugin directories). I found this Stack Overflow posting as very helpful in finding my answer: [Where Jenkins stores plugin configuration](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40339386/where-jenkins-stores-plugin-configuration)